# Is there an equivalent to "Do not use recursion for this domain" in Server 2008/Win7?

Tags: windows, domain-name-system

When setting up conditional forwarders in Server 2003, there is an option which says "Do not use recursion for this domain". This option acts only on the zone currently selected in the forwarders list. In the server 2008/Windows 7 snap-in, this interface has been replaced, and I cannot find an equivalent option. The closest option works at the server level, which I do not want.

Comment: I have found the same problem. There is much discussion on other forums but everyone is focusing on the options at server level or on the option to prevent use of root hints on the property page which applies to unconditional rather than conditional forwarders. Not found any suggestion that Microsoft recognise this yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you can still do it from command line, with /slave switch:

```
dnscmd <ServerName> /ZoneAdd <ZoneName> /Forwarder <MasterIPaddress ...> [/TimeOut <Time>] [/Slave]
```

Comment: I'm hoping there's something in the GUI. I certainly don't have a problem with the command line, but if another administrator is using the GUI and the setting isn't visible from there, I can see the potential for human error to creep in.